# Need clarification on window.siteData in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have come across a variable in javascript called window.sitedata but tried to search the details regarding it but unable to find.
Can some explain what is window.sitedata in java script ? what is its purpose, any documentation regarding it would be helpful.

Comment: It is a custom variable, not a native `window` property. What is the context? A library ..? Notice, that every globally declared variable can be referred via `window`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `window.sitedata` is not available. Refer below link for window object properties.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ex_browser.asp

FYI
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Answer (score 0):

`sitedata` is a custom variable because the native `window` object does not have a property called `sitedata`.

You may ask (if possible) the programmer who developed the code.

Reference:

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)